# Get columns with value 0 on `group by` with `count`

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query to get the count  of rows  grouped by `cmp2` field but I need to get a column for every `cmp2` even if its sum result is `0`. I can't get it this way:

```
SELECT CMP2, COALESCE(count(*), 0) as count 
FROM datos_con851_0,
     datos_con851_1  
WHERE datos_con851_0.REGISTRO = datos_con851_1.REGISTRO 
  AND SPEEDER = 1
GROUP BY CMP2;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed!

Comment: Qualify all columns, so we know which table they belong to. Like `table.column`.

Comment: You write SUM multiple times but your code contains COUNT?

Comment: You say "I need to get a column for every cmp2"... what does that mean. Your SELECT only has two columns and the output will have two columns. Do you mean "Row"? Perhaps a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a CASE would help, but we can only guess unless you share your schema, sample data and desired results. Your wrong SQL is not enough for us to reverse engineer into a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join`, presumably something like this:

```
SELECT d0.CMP2, count(d1.REGISTRO) as count 
FROM datos_con851_0 d0 left join
     datos_con851_1 d1
     on d0.REGISTRO = d1.REGISTRO AND
        d1.SPEEDER = 1  -- just guess this comes from `d1`
GROUP BY d0.CMP2;
```